How do I create a Maven project library from within an IntelliJ plugin?
I’m attempting to copy a global maven library to the project level, using the IntelliJ plug-in API.
I tried following the steps at “Creating a Library” at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/library.html, but that creates a regular library, not a Maven library.
I'm able to create a "regular" library like the slf4j library shown below.
How can I create a "Maven" library (with the blue 'm' icon) in the screenshot below, using the IntelliJ plug-in API?


I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to create a maven library, you can do it from intellij. But if you want a library to show as it comes from maven, it will need to be in the maven local cache (and maybe published on a maven repo).

I know I can do it using the GUI in IntelliJ. I'm trying to write a plug-in for IntelliJ that accomplishes the same thing.

Here's the solution I came up with. This is based on code from com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.classpath.ChangeLibraryLevelActionBase.doCopy(LibraryEx library)
private void copyGlobalLibraryToProject( Project project, String libraryName ) {
    LibraryTable globalTable = LibraryTablesRegistrar.getInstance().getLibraryTable();
    final LibraryEx sourceLibrary = Objects.requireNonNull( (LibraryEx )globalTable.getLibraryByName( libraryName ) );
    LibraryTable libraryTable = LibraryTablesRegistrar.getInstance().getLibraryTable(project);
    final LibraryTable.ModifiableModel modifiableModel = libraryTable.getModifiableModel();

    final Set<File> fileToCopy = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    final Map<String, String> copiedFiles = new HashMap<>();
        for (OrderRootType type : OrderRootType.getAllTypes()) {
            for (VirtualFile root : sourceLibrary.getFiles(type)) {
                if (root.isInLocalFileSystem() || root.getFileSystem() instanceof ArchiveFileSystem ) {
                    fileToCopy.add( VfsUtilCore.virtualToIoFile( VfsUtil.getLocalFile(root)));
                }
            }
        }
        fileToCopy.forEach( from -> copiedFiles.put( FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName(from.getAbsolutePath()), FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName(from.getAbsolutePath()) ) );

    final Library copied = modifiableModel.createLibrary( libraryName, sourceLibrary.getKind());
    final LibraryEx.ModifiableModelEx model = (LibraryEx.ModifiableModelEx)copied.getModifiableModel();
    LibraryEditingUtil.copyLibrary(sourceLibrary, copiedFiles, model);

    WriteAction.run(() -> {
        model.commit();
        modifiableModel.commit();
    });
}

